# Are there any open source libraries for performing FFTs on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, signal-processing, fft

I would like to compare to WAV audio files using an FFT.  What open source libraries and / or sample code exist for performing such an operation?

Answer (score 2):

Apple's aurioTouch sample app (available on the developer.apple.com web site) includes source code for an FFT (not as fast as the one in the iOS4 Accelerate framework though).  The sample app also contains a source code example of how to use an FFT to process audio input data, which is very similar to the raw PCM data contained in a .wav file after the header.

Answer (score 0):

Accelerate.framework

Comment: I know we should use the above framework.how to implement it.any sample codes or documents be more useful.

Comment: it's been available on OS X for years. if the documentation and samples relevant to iOS are too sparse, then refer to the OS X samples and docs for additional demonstrations.

Comment: @Warrior - See this: http://developer.apple.com/performance/accelerateframework.html as well as the WWDC 2010 Session 202 - The Accelerate framework for iPhone OS.

Comment: @Warrior - In fact, the vDSP Programming Guide in Apple's documentation has sample code for performing an FFT within it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/SampleCode/SampleCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH205-45465